# One addEventListener seems to be deactivated by another one

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

In order to learn Javascript, I created a little website on local. 
I have a menu composed of "li", a empty "div", and several "section".
When a click is done on a "li", the appropriate "section" goes into the empty "div" and its class="hidden" is removed.

To make this, I have a loop on my "li" and when there is a click on one of them, a function swapContent() is called inside the li.addEventListener...

Everything works fine ! But, in one specific "section", I have buttons that also work with a click and addEventListener. And that doesn't work.

When I comment the code inside my script file and test it with the console, it works but not when it's called from the script.

I also tried including the javascript code related to those buttons inside the "li" loop right after where the addEventListener (click) with the swapContent() are called and it works !

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

const frame = document.getElementById('frame');

function swapSection(liText, secId){
    let section = document.getElementById(secId);
    let clone = section.cloneNode(true);
    clone.classList.remove('hidden');        
    while (frame.firstChild) frame.firstChild.remove();        
    frame.appendChild(clone); 
    let h2Select = document.getElementsByClassName('hero');
    h2Select[0].innerText = liText;  
}; 

// -- Navigation --    

var liList = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="li_"]');

for (var item of liList) {
    let li = item;
    let liId = li.id;
    let liText = li.innerText;

    // if <li> has an ID show section onclick
    if (liId) {
        const reg = /li/i;
        let secId = liId.replace(reg, 'sct');   

        // Display content into frame on item menu's click
        li.addEventListener('click', function(){
            swapSection(liText, secId);
        }, false);
    }    
};

// Buttons that don't work
const toChange = document.getElementById('toChange');
const btnDisable = document.getElementById('disable');
const btnEnable = document.getElementById('enable');

btnEnable.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   toChange.setAttribute("disabled", false);
   toChange.innerText = 'Not Clickable'
   }
);    

btnDisable.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   toChange.removeAttribute("disabled");
   toChange.innerText = "Clickable";
});
});
```

The code on https://codepen.io/Franz333/pen/vqGLZE

Thank you in advance

Comment: you should provide your code

Comment: You need to share some demo. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just did, thank you